# Get data and make changes on javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object. 
But i don't know how to get the ID because it change for each page.
So if make:

```
var obj = bundle.config.options
```

I get this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHSPP.jpg

Then, i want to get in a var the number of the object -> '42' in this case

And then, i want to insert into the selection, and i hope it was like:

```
bundle.config.options[42].selections[314]
```

And then change the fields.
Am i confused?

How could get this value?

**UPDATE**

I have associate by loop of other objets, the minQty of products for each product.

```
$minimumQty = $_selection->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();


                echo("<script>
                    var obj = bundle.config.options ;
                    var a = Object.keys(obj);

                    var keys = [];
                    for(var k in obj[a].selections) keys.push(k);


                    obj[a].selections[keys[d]].minQty = ".$minimumQty."
                      </script><br>");
```

The result -> each selection have the field: minQty with their number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Object.keys(obj)`, here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on how it is used.

OR

You can loop through you Object and get the keys

```
var keys = [];
for(var k in obj) keys.push(k);
```